# Slow Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation. Why?

Tags: python, optimization, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I wanted to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes to its basic level with no optimisation on checking up to the square root or similar.

I do not see why this implementation is so slow... It takes around 110 seconds to run the sieve for 10^5, which is significantly slower than similar implementations.

Could some one care to explain where the culprit is?

```
def sieve(n, out = True):
    start_time = time.time()
    isPrime = [True] * (n-1) # (n-1) since we do not include 0 or 1
    p = 2

    while True:
        multiplier = 2
        multiple = p*multiplier
        # mark all multiples of p as False
        while multiple <= n:
            isPrime[multiple-2] = False # subtract 2 since the list starts at 2. Hence indices and numbers are shifted by 2
            multiplier +=1
            multiple = p*multiplier
        # change p to next prime
        for i, prime in enumerate(isPrime):
            if prime and i+2>p: #remember indices are off by 2 
                p = i+2
                break
        else:
            break
    end_time = time.time()
    if out:
        for i, prime in enumerate(isPrime):
            if prime:
                print(i+2)

    print("Computation took: %0.05f" % (end_time- start_time))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simplify the code and it'll go fast:

```
from time import time
def sieve(n, out = True):
    start_time = time()
    isPrime = [True] * (n + 1) 

    for p in range(2, n + 1):
        for multiple in range(p * 2, n + 1, p):
            isPrime[multiple] = False

    end_time = time()
    if out:
        for i, prime in enumerate(isPrime):
            if prime and i > 1:
                print(i)

    print("Computation took: %0.05f" % (end_time- start_time))
```

Computation took: 0.09900 seconds

Answer (score 2):

You do more work than is necessary. You converted addition to multiplication while sieving, and both the starting point and ending point of sieving are larger than necessary. Here is my implementation, which fixes those problems and also handles 2 as a special case:

```
def primes(n): # sieve of eratosthenes
    i, p, ps, m = 0, 3, [2], n // 2
    sieve = [True] * m
    while p <= n:
        if sieve[i]:
            ps.append(p)
            for j in range((p*p-3)/2, m, p):
                sieve[j] = False
        i, p = i+1, p+2
    return ps
```